# How to check which test script is/will be the last one to execute? (Using C# and NUnit)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

In Automation testing solution (C# and Nunit) I want to fetch the name of test script which is the last one to execute.

Comment: Since "test script" is not a term used in NUnit and is used in different ways by different people, please define what you mean by it so we can give an answer. For example, are you talking about a test case? a fixture? etc.

Comment: @Charlie - By test script I mean a test case.

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question... this is not extremely easy, but it's possible...

You can create both `[OneTimeTearDown]` and `[TearDown]` methods that reference a static variable. For example

```
private static string _lastTestRun;

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void RecordLastTestCase()
{
    // Do what you like with _lastTestRun
}

[TearDown]
public void My TearDown()
{
    _lastTestRun = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
}
```

You haven't said what you are trying to accomplish with this information. Depending on what that is, something simpler might be possible.